# Sum file txt using scanner java

Tags: java

I have data in file **file.txt** :`1,2,3` and I want to sum all of data text. How should be proceed?

```
int a[] = new int [5];
int h=0;
String  fileName = "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt";
File textFile = new File (fileName);
Scanner in = new Scanner (textFile);

while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    String Line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(Line);`enter code here`
}
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        h +=a[i];   
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.print("Sum is : " + h);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **nextInt()** method to get each integer in iteration. (I am considering you have only integers in your file)

Initialize a **sum** variable to **0**  and produce sum at each iteration.

**Example**

```
int sum = 0;
while(in.hasNextInt()){
sum +=in.nextInt();
}
```

There might me minor errors but this is the idea. Finally when the loop stops, you have sum in **sum** variable

Comment: thanks its great work... i want to ask to you 1 more, if i have data {1,2,3}, {2,3,4} using array can i producing separately? ex column 1 : 1,2,3 produce 6 and column 2 produce 9... thanks Mr

Comment: @rickyhitman10 Yes you can. Use the **hasNextLine()** method and inside the method use **split()** method to split and get the sum

Comment: can you explain and giving examples to me, because i still beginner, and not understand about programme language...

Comment: @rickyhitman10 I think you should ask a new question for it. Good luck. I will surely help you there. I cannot answer here because that would be off-topic. Sorry.